# Magento - Editing phtml files in adminhtml folder having no effect

Tags: magento, admin, upgrade, php, adminhtml

When I make a change to **“app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml”** or other files in the adminhtml folders, the changes I make have no effect on the site. The site seems to be using old versions of my files but I have no idea where it is getting them from. I have deleted the cache multiple times and logged in/out of admin. I’ve also managed to turn on path hints in the admin panel and can see that the correct files are being used but the code in the files is incorrect. If I rename the file to _head.phtml then as you'd expect, the styling, js and meta tags etc go missing but when I make a simple edit to that same file the change is not reflected.

I recently upgraded from 1.6.2 to 1.7 - Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing magento cache?

Comment: also, make sure to empty your browser cache completely and try again.

Comment: if you make an edit and save then view source do you see your changes? If not then permissions might be a bit wonky. You have permissions to rename the file but not to write to the file therefore when clicking save your IDE might just be making a temp copy somewhere instead. It's a long shot I know but hey!

Comment: There was a setting under /etc/php.d/apc.ini which was set to production mode. When in production mode the APC cache will not check if a file has been modified if it exists in the cache already. When in development mode this check occurs. I have enabled development mode and everything is back to normal.

More Reading:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

So the problem was caching. Just not where I expected. Thanks for the replies.